# Gazebo2 with black screen

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

I  just install gazebo2 on 14.04 Ubuntu. Everytime I run gazebo. It shows nothing but black screen or broken pics. Does the problem have something to do with the graphic card? I use Intel Broadwell integrated graphic.

[image: image description]

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12773/gazebo2-with-black-screen/) by [ypfeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2492/ypfeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leEngineer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2460/leengineer/) on 2016-03-06**:
Please, run by terminal with the command gazebo --verbose and feedback with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I had the same problem as you! My configurations are:

```
lsb_release -a
```

> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>
> Description:  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
>
> Release:  14.04 Codename: trusty

```
lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2
```

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller:
>
> Intel Corporation Broadwell-U
>
> Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
>
> Subsystem: Dell Device 0643     Kernel
>
> driver in use: i915

After some research, I found this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/624979/background-freezes-weirdly-in-ubuntu-14-04/624984?noredirect=1#comment886110_624984) which suggest to upgrade the kernel and graphical stack with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Gazebo started to "work" again, as you can see:

[image: image description]

I hope this answer can be helpfull.

Best regards

---

Originally posted by [leEngineer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2460/leengineer/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1